# Where to use Thread interupt

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have some old code I am working with, and I'm not too experienced with Threads (mostly work on the front end).  Anyway, this Thread.sleep is causing the thread to hang and I'm unsure what to do about it.  I thought about using a counter and throwing a Thread.currentThread.interupt, but unsure of where to put it or which thread it will interupt.  Here is an example of the dump.  As you can see the thread count is getting pretty high at 1708.

Any advice?

> "Thread-1708" prio=6 tid=0x2ceec400 nid=0x2018 waiting on condition
>   [0x36cdf000]    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)    Locked ownable synchronizers:
>     - None "Thread-1707" prio=6 tid=0x2d16b800 nid=0x215c waiting on condition [0x36c8f000]    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
>   (sleeping)    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)    Locked ownable
>   synchronizers:
>     - None

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    Connection con = null;
    int i = 0;

    while (is_running)
    {
        try
        {
            con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();

            while (!stack.isEmpty())
            {
                COUNT++;
                String line = (String) stack.pop();
                getPartMfr(line);
                try
                {
                    if (this.mfr != null && !this.mfr.equals(EMPTY_STR))
                    {
                        lookupPart(con, line);
                    }
                }
                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (COUNT % 1000 == 0)
                {
                    Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
                    log.info("Processing Count: " + COUNT);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (NamingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                ConnectionManager.close(con);
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        try {
            Thread.sleep(80);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    this.finished = true;

}
```

Here is where it calls the run method, as you can see it does set it to false, but I guess it is missing threads?

```
    HarrisWorker w[] = new HarrisWorker[WORKER_POOL_SIZE];
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++)
        {
            w[i] = new HarrisWorker(pw);
            w[i].start();
        }
        pw.println(headers());
        File inputDir = new File(HARRIS_BASE);
        String files[] = inputDir.list();
        for (String file : files)
        {

            try
            {
                File f = new File(HARRIS_BASE + File.separator + file);
                if (f.isDirectory())
                    continue;
                final String workFile = workDir + File.separator + file;
                f.renameTo(new File(workFile));

                FileReader fr = new FileReader(workFile);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String line = br.readLine();

                boolean firstLine = true;

                while (line != null)
                {
                    if (firstLine)
                    {
                        firstLine = false;
                        line = br.readLine();
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (line.startsWith(","))
                    {
                        line = br.readLine();
                        continue;
                    }
                    //          if(line.indexOf("103327-1") == -1)
                    //          {
                    //              line = br.readLine();
                    //              continue;
                    //          }
                    HarrisWorker.stack.push(line);
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
                br.close();
                fr.close();
                for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++)
                {
                    w[i].is_running = false;

                    while (!w[i].finished)
                    {

                        Thread.sleep(80);   
                    }

                }
                move2Processed(file, workFile);
                long etime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("UNIQUE PARTS TOTAL FOUND: " + HarrisWorker.getFoundCount() + " of " + HarrisWorker.getUniqueCount() + ", "
                        + (HarrisWorker.getFoundCount() / HarrisWorker.getUniqueCount()));
                System.out.println("Time: " + (etime - time));


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                File f = new File(workDir + File.separator + file);
                if (f.exists())
                {
                    f.renameTo(new File(HARRIS_BASE + File.separator + ERROR + File.separator + file));
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to interrupt it? You are seeing it in `sleep` because that is where it **should** spend most of it's time - asleep. The name "Thread-1708" does not mean there are 1708 threads running.

Comment: Well, after about a week there gets to be so many threads that it bogs down our server and we have to dump and restart.  Our server admin just said there are thousands of threads sleeping, I just wanted a way to close them out after a certain amount of time or something.  If it would help I could send you the full thread dump, I've tried reading up on threading but it's still a little confusing to me.

Comment: In that case just set the `run` instance variable to `false` and the threads will close and terminate. Your difficulty is probably finding the right place in code to do that - start with where these threads are created and why. Better still - consider using a thread pool.

Comment: I updated my code to include the one that creates the worker threads.

Comment: Make sure `is_running` is marked `volatile`. Use `Thread.join()` instead of your strange loop looking for `finished`. Log every creation of a thread and every completion - your problem should become clearer. Consider using a [Thread Pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html).

Answer (score 2):

As a direct answer to the question in your title - nowhere. There is nowhere in this code that needs a `Thread.interrupt()`.

The fact that the thread name is `Thread-1708` does not necessarily mean there are 1708 threads. One can choose arbitrary names for threads. I usually include the name of the executor or service in the thread name. Maybe 1600 are now long stopped and there are only around a hundred alive. Maybe this particular class starts naming at 1700 to distinguish from other uses.

1708 threads may not be a problem. If you have a multi-threaded server that is serving 2000 connections in parallel, then it certainly expectable that there are 2000 threads doing that, along with a bunch of other threads.

You have to understand why the `sleep` is there and what purpose it serves. It's not there to just hog memory for nothing.

Translating the code to "plaintext" (btw it can be greatly simplified by using `try-with-resources` to acquire and close the connection):

- Acquire a connection
- Use the connection to send (I guess) whatever is in the stack
- When failed or finished - wait 80ms (THIS is your `sleep`)
- If `run` flag is still set - repeat from step 1
- Finish the thread.

Now reading through this, it's *obvious* that it's not the `sleep` that's the problem. It's that the `run` flag is not set to false. And your thread just continues looping, even if it can't get the connection at all - it will simply spend most of its time waiting for the retry. In fact - even if you completely strip the `sleep` out (instead of interrupting it mid-way), all you will achieve is that the `Threads` will start using up more resources. Given that you have both a logger *and* you print to `stdout` via `printStackTrace`, I would say that you have 2 problems:

- Something is spawning threads and not stopping them afterwards (not setting their `run` flag to `false` when done)
- You are likely getting exceptions when getting the `Connection`, but you never see them in the log.

It might be that the Thread is supposed to set it's own `run` flag (say when the stack is drained), but you would have to decide that yourself - that depends on a lot of specifics.

Comment: Updated my code to include the code that calls it.  The run flag should be closed outside of the run in the other code.

Comment: And an entire host of problems became visible. OldCurmudgeon gave a very good point - if `is_running` is not `volatile` then there's no guarantee that they will stop. Also, note that if you have some kind of exception while reading the file, then you never stop the threads - that code should be in the absent `finally`, not the end of the `try`. And lastly - there are a number of structures and methods to wait for the completion of a bunch of `Thread`s. `Thread.join` is the most primitive one. A `CountdownLatch` may work better. This loop invites more visibility and concurrency issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but some things you should know if you are writing code for a live, production systemn:

**:-(**  Variable and method both have the same name, `run`.  A better name for the variable might be `keep_running`  Or, change the sense of it so that you can write `while (! time_to_shut_down) { ... }`

**:-(**  `Thread.sleep(80)`  What is this for?  It looks like a big red flag to me.  You can never fix a concurrency bug by adding a `sleep()` call to your code.  All you can do is make the bug less likely to happen in testing.  That means, when the bug finally *does* bite, it will bite you in the production system.

**:-(** Your `run()` method is *way* too complicated (the keyword `try` appears four times).  Break it up, please.

**:-(** Ignoring five different exceptions `catch (MumbleFoobarException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`  Most of those exceptions (but maybe not the InterruptedException) mean that *something is wrong*.  Your program should *do* something more than just write a message to the standard output.

**:-(** Writing error messages to standard output.  You should be calling `log.error(...)` so that your application can be configured to send the messages to someplace where somebody might actually *see* them.

Comment: Actually so many `try` are necessary - since the code looks like have been written before Java 7 + what is IMHO a minor design flaw. The `Thread.sleep` looks like it's not there for solving concurrency issues, but rather as a replacement for proper blocking queues and as a retry delay. It *does* work correctly (not just makes it "less likely"), although using a randomized delay and a blocking collection would be better. None of this actually addresses the issue at hand though.

Comment: Updated my code to include the code that calls this.

Comment: I'm not saying that all of those try blocks are not needed.  I'm saying that they should not all be in the same method body.  The `run()` method could be broken up into a number of other subroutines which, if they were well named, would make the code a lot easier to understand.